# How to use box3d shape in graphviz using DiagrammeR?

Tags: r, graphviz, diagrammer

I want to use the `box3d` shape in `graphviz` using `DiagrammeR` in `R`:

[image]

(Screenshot was taken from their official website at https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html)

When I do:

```
DiagrammeR::grViz("digraph {
                  
box [label = B, shape = box3d]

}")
```

I get:

[image]

This means the `shape` argument cannot recognise the shape. For example, when I use another `shape` it works just fine:

```
DiagrammeR::grViz("digraph {
                  
box [label = B, shape = circle]

}")
```

which produces:

[image]

Comment: Your example code works fine on my Mac using R 4.2.0 and Diagrammer 1.0.9.

Comment: @stefan thanks for letting me know. I updated the package using `devtools::install_github("rich-iannone/DiagrammeR")` and now it works!